# Running analyses with uneven group sizes

Tags: anova, group-differences

I was trying to run a study with 100 people per condition for 4 conditions. When I looked at the results, the group sizes were skewed - some had 80, some had 120. If I'm planning on running a series of two-way ANOVAs, would the uneven group sizes negatively affect the results?

Comment: What is your impression of the effect of group size?

Comment: That larger, more-even group sizes are better? I'm not sure I see what you're getting at.